# Given two local parameterizations and corresponding fundamental forms, find a $2\times 2$ matrix that equates them.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Horridly written title, but please see the image below for the problem statement:

[image]

I'm not sure how to use the chain rule to express the first differentials in terms of the second. I know the answer is some kind of Jacobian matrix but I don't see the derivation path in front of me.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Fix a point on the surface. In a neighbourhood of that point, you have two bases for $T_pS$. These are $\{\sigma_u,\sigma_v\}$ and $\{\widetilde\sigma_u,\widetilde\sigma_v\}$. The first fundamental form is just the quadratic form given by $I(v)=\langle v,v\rangle$. It follows the $E,F,G$ and $\widetilde E,\widetilde F,\widetilde G$ are just the entries of the symmetric matrix representing the bilinear form $\langle,\rangle$ in the respective bases.

Hence you just need to find the change of basis matrix between the two bases. You know that $\sigma_u=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)$, where $\sigma(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$. Similarly for $\sigma_v$. Now use the chain rule to express $\{\widetilde\sigma_u,\widetilde\sigma_v\}$ as a linear combination of  $\{\sigma_u,\sigma_v\}$.